# Synchronizing record navigation control and record selection combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form bound to a query, with controls bound to fields of the query.
I also have an unbound combobox, whose `Row Source` is the same query, used to select the current form record via its `After Update` event handler:

```
Private Sub Loc_cbo_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "ID = " & Str(Nz(Loc_cbo, 0))
End Sub
```

The combobox has three columns:

1. the `Bound Column`, an invisible ID,
2. a location code,
3. a location name.

The combo's `Row Source` is `SELECT * FROM Sites ORDER BY Loc DESC`. (Originally, it was just `Sites` but since I have the form's `Order By` as `Site.Loc DESC`, I wanted the order to match.)

It works fine.
Of course, I can *also* navigate through the form’s records via its navigation control (First, Previous, Next, Last).
That, too, works.
However, I’d like the combobox to be synchronized with the current record as it changes via the navigation control.

I’ve tried to do it via the form’s `Current` event handler, three different ways.
First, to set the combobox’s Text value to match that of the corresponding textbox control

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Loc_cbo.SetFocus
    Loc_cbo.Text = Loc_txt ‘ ERROR
End Sub
```

but I get

> Run-time error ‘2101’: The setting you entered isn’t valid for this
>   property.

Second, to set the combobox’s ListIndex value relative to the current record

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Loc_cbo.SetFocus
    Loc_cbo.ListIndex = CurrentRecord - 1 ‘ ERROR
End Sub
```

but I get either the same Run-time error ‘2101’ or

> Run-time error ‘7777’: You’ve used the ListIndex property incorrectly.

in the same place.

Third, (thanks to HansUp's early answer) to set the combobox’s Value property:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Loc_cbo.Value = Loc_txt.Value 
End Sub
```

This "works" in so far as there is no error message and, according to debug.prints, the value of `Loc_cbo` does change to match that of `Loc_txt`. However, the visible textbox-like portion of the combobox now appears to be empty/blank (nothing in it) always.

How can I get the record selector combobox to agree with the current record when the latter has been changed via the record navigator? 
I cannot believe users will be happy having the two out of synch.
I also cannot believe I haven't found this problem described anywhere else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign to the combo's `.Value` property to change its selection.  For `.Value`, you don't need to `SetFocus`.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.Loc_cbo.Value = Me.Loc_txt.Value
End Sub
```

Note this suggestion assumes the combo's `.Value` is what you want to match to  the text box value.  Check to confirm you want the match between the combo and text box to be based on the combo's `.Value` instead of another of the combo's columns.

**Post mortem**:

The content of the text box was intended to match one of the combo's columns.  However, since the combo's *Bound Column* contains numbers associated with that other column, Martin used a `DLookup` expression to fetch the number which corresponds to the text box content and assigned that number to the combo's `.Value` property:

```vb
Me.Loc_cbo.Value = DLookup("ID", "Sites", "Loc= '" & Me.Loc_txt.Value & "'")
```

Note a combo's `.Value` is the value in the *Bound Column* of its selected row.

Comment: Worked on first attempt! Maybe you want to edit *this* into your answer: `Me.Loc_cbo.Value = DLookup("ID", "Sites", "Loc= '" & Me.Loc_txt.Value & "'")`

Comment: Well done, Sir!  Please feel free to edit my description if you can make it easier to understand.